# How to deploy a sybase proc from java class

Tags: java

I have 10-12 procs which I need to deploy in Sybase server to work on my project.It's quite difficult and time consuming to repeat this process every time.I'm writing a java class which will make a connection and then read those files and just deploy it in the server.

But I'm getting SybSqlException.

Following is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class PlayProcsExecutor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String DB_URL = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:abc.net:3700";
    String USER = "1234";
    String PASS = "abcd";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuffer stringBufer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\dummy_hi.sql"));
      String currentString = null;
      while ((currentString = br.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBufer.append(currentString);
        System.out.println(currentString);
      }
      String sql;
      sql = stringBufer.toString();
      System.out.println(sql);
      boolean rs = stmt.execute(sql);
      if (rs) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
      } else {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
      }
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Following is the proc :

```
use ams_trading

go

if object_id("#batch_mdl_list") is not null

    drop table #batch_mdl_list

go

create table #batch_mdl_list

(
    id_batch int not null,

    id_mdl int not null

)

if object_id("dummy_hi") != null

    drop proc dummy_hi

go

create proc dummy_hi

    @cd_stage varchar(12) = 'ALL',

    @debug int = 0

as

    select "HI"

go

if object_id("#batch_mdl_list") is not null

    drop table #batch_mdl_list

go

grant execute on dummy_hi to wm_role

go
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'object_id'.

    at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.executeLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at PlayProcsExecutor.main(PlayProcsExecutor.java:44)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [flyaway](http://flywaydb.org/), a java tool for db migration and version control.

Another alternative is [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) but I find it more heavyweight than flyaway.

Flyaway can be embedded in your application and run on startup or can be triggered via ant/maven/gradle etc.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it without the help of any tools?

Comment: Yes, but you probably need to split the script up into seperate `java.sql.Statement`s for each `go`

Comment: I was hoping if execute can handle "alter table" then probably it'll also be able to do this.But even if I delete all the if object_id things, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run the script with a single execute.

Try splitting the string for every "go" and running `java.sql.Statement.execute(...)` for each substring. Note, I think you need to remove "go" from what is executed.

eg

```
stmt.execute("use ams_trading");
stmt.execute("if object_id('#batch_mdl_list') is not null drop table #batch_mdl_list");
stmt.execute("create table #batch_mdl_list (id_batch int not null, id_mdl int not null)");
...
```

Comment: I did something like this while ((currentString = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(currentString.length() != 0 && !"go".equals(currentString)){
          stmt.execute(currentString);
        }        
        //stringBufer.append(currentString);
        System.out.println(currentString);
      }  Now it says The quoted identifier '"#batch_mdl_list"' is illegal because its first character is '#', which is ambiguous. Please use another character instead.
.